# Routing doesn't work in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

I had installed Laravel with the following command

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

And everything is fine when I open `/ root`. I saw "You have arrived." page but I can't make any route.When I write the following simple route I saw the page not found error.

```
Route::get('hello', function() {
 return 'Hello World';
});
```

---

error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /afifnet/public/hello was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80 please help me.
```

Comment: Is `/afifnet/public/` the root of your site?

Comment: Is there .htaccess in your public folder? Answer is yes so `mod_rewrite` is already on your Apache? (if you are using Apache)

Comment: Possible mod_rewrite isn't install or enable.

Comment: is solved tanks all mod_rewrite is't install

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. When you create a route you need to make sure you have a view. You can create a view by going the views folder (make sure you have the extension `.blade.php`

Create a View in your views folder (and add some content), eg:

```
test.blade.php
```

Then in your routes.php file add this:

```
Route::get('/test', function() { 

return View::make('test'); 

});
```

Now goto public/test and you should see the content you added to test.blade.php file.

If you still cannot create a route it's another issue, however seeing as you can see the landing page "you have arrived" everything should be working.

Comment: That's not true. You could return an Eloquent object that's automatically converted to JSON, for instance. Or you could just dd() something to make sure the route works. If missing a view was the issue, OP would have gotten a completely different error message.